# ALTER TABLE tbl_taxsetup MODIFY COLUMN StartDate DateTime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ;

Tags: mysql, sql

My requirement is I want to Set the time user not enter time,in the column time ....
Date which is user enter one...both combination i Want to set in Some filed Name "StartDate" type is DATETIME =2013-04-27 20:00:00 like this
But 20:00:00  not enter by the user by default i want to set this time, as **select time(now())** .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with DATE/DATETIME fields, because DEFAULT clause does not support using functions like NOW(). But you could create a trigger to set current date/time field value if it is NULL.

As a workaround, try to use TIMESTAMP field, it supports `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, which will help you to set default date/time. More information - [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)